# PHP switch statement problem causes a syntax error

Tags: php, switch-statement, php-7.4

My code:

```php
<?php
    $i = 1;
    switch ($i) {
?>
        
        <?php
            case 1:
        ?>
        $i is 1
        <?php
            break;
        ?>
<?php
    }
?>
```

This code gives me an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ' ', expecting case (T_CASE) or default (T_DEFAULT) or '}' in D:\xampp\htdocs\php-mvc\public\test.php on line 5
```

I know that I can avoid closing php tags and say `echo 'text';` but still, how to fix this?

Comment: `switch ($i) {
?>
        
        <?php`... closing and opening the brackets here serves no purpose. It's the same after the `break;`...it doesn't do anything useful

Comment: why not just do `echo '$i is ' . $i;` you don't need a switch, extra steps.. https://3v4l.org/KJcg9

Comment: @ADyson, LawrenceCherone This is just an example. The actual code is quite complex and large, so I did not post that here.

Comment: Well you can't possibly be having any code in between those `?>   <?php` that I pointed out, otherwise you'd have an error. You already have one due to just the empty space in between...so I don't know what you think you've omitted that would be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are breaking the switch syntax off by outputting empty spaces when closing and opening the PHP tag.

This will work:

```
<?php
    $i = 1;
    switch ($i) {
            case 1:
        ?>
        $i is 1
        <?php
            break;
        ?>
<?php
    }
?>
```